# Python format function behavior with `:`

Tags: python, string, google-analytics, format

Good day, everyone,

First of all, I would like to share the idea of the task that I solved using this code. Then, I will explain what results I expect. Afterward, I will show you a part of the code.

We have a project where we used mapping of columns for different sources. In this particular case, we need to extract two separate values from a dictionary using keys as paths.

Here is data:

`{'ga:userType': 'New Visitor', 'ga:source': 'source', 'ga:adContent': 'some_value', 'ga:eventLabel': 'company_added', 'ga:dateHourMinute': '202305181019', 'ga:users': '1'}`

The next step is to extract two values using this construction:

`path: '{ga:adContent}_{ga:dateHourMinute}'`

After that, I will use this function to transform them into one value.

```
def the_name(
        cls,
        action: Dict,
        format_string: str,
    ) -> Any:
        try:
            return descriptor_notation_string.format(**action)
        except (KeyError, TypeError, IndexError) as e:
            raise FieldNotExistsError()
```

And I get a KeyError here in  except part as e = 'ga'. Based on this error, I assume that the standard format function fails when attempting to parse my value `'{ga:adContent}_{ga:dateHourMinute}'` in the 'builtins.py' module.

```
 def format(self, *args, **kwargs): # known special case of str.format
        """
        S.format(*args, **kwargs) -> str
        
        Return a formatted version of S, using substitutions from args and kwargs.
        The substitutions are identified by braces ('{' and '}').
        """
        pass
```

I cannot reuse this piece of code because it includes very basic behavior. However, in this particular instance, it appears that my data was not collected as expected.

I tried as well use double `{{` instead of `{`
didn't work.
Is there a way I can substitute values into a formatted string by keys other than this formatting method? Perhaps I should approach this issue from a different angle. I would appreciate any advice you may have. Thank you very much for your time. This is my first question, and I am mustering the courage to ask!"

Here is reproducible code example:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dict_of_actions = {'ga:userType': 'New Visitor', 'ga:source': 'source', 'ga:adContent': 'random_hash1',
                       'ga:eventLabel': 'company_added', 'ga:dateHourMinute': '202305181019', 'ga:users': '1'}

    string_with_path = '{ga:adContent}_{ga:dateHourMinute}'

    def _get_node_value_by_format_string(
            action: Dict,
            format_string: str
    ) -> Any:

        try:
            return format_string.format(**action)
        except (KeyError, TypeError, IndexError) as e:
            raise Exception(e)


    result = _get_node_value_by_format_string(dict_of_actions, string_with_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Because *arg_name* is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings `'10'` or `':-]'`) within a format string.

The `:` in the key is interpreted as the delimiter between the field name and the format spec. The caller of the function needs to be aware of this, and pass a correct format string and/or dictionary.

Comment: Yes, the error you interpreted is correct, but I cannot inherit from this function as it would be like a crutch solution. I was thinking of checking if there is a `:` character and try to parse it, but the fields in the initial data also have the same names. Therefore, I still need to concatenate them somehow while referencing those keys.